# Saving labels created at run-time

Tags: vb.net, save

I am using this code to add labels to my form but when I close the form they all disappear. Is there a way to save the labels or to create a text document that will load every time and restore the labels?

```
 Private x As Integer = 12
  Private y As Integer = 180

 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lbl As New label
    lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23) 'set your size
    lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(x, y) 'set your location
    lbl.Text = (TextBox1.Text) 'set your name
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)  'add your new control to your forms control collection
    x += 10 'arbitrary value, you could adjust y, too
End Sub
```

Comment: Create a custom class to hold Size(), Location() and Text().  No add instances of that class to a List().  Save the list to an XML file with the XmlSerializer.  Reverse the process to put the Labels back when the form opens.

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19143430/1070452

Answer (score 1):

To have them persistent you need to add them from the toolbox at design time.

Have a look at this for instructions:

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s1p6.html

Alternatively you need to have a configuration file that you save every time a control is added, with the appropriate properties and then you can recreate these from the configuration file when the form loads.

(I'm assuming you are using Winforms?)

Comment: i know that thank you but i am working on the project where a person can add labels when the need them